# <table> não exibe os dados que estou passando

Tags: java

```
public List<Paises> getAllAmericaSul() {
    List<Paises> listaAmericaSul = new ArrayList<Paises>();
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select nome_pais, tipo_medida, total_focos, ano_medida FROM fato f INNER JOIN apaises p ON p.id_paises = f.paises_id_paises INNER JOIN aps.indicador i ON i.id_indicador = f.indicador_id_indicador WHERE nome_continente = 'America do Sul'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Paises americaSul = new Paises();
            americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nome_pais"));
            americaSul.setTipoMedida(rs.getString("tipo_medida"));
            americaSul.setTotalFocos(rs.getInt("total_focos"));
            americaSul.setDataMedida(rs.getInt("ano_medida"));
            listaAmericaSul.add(americaSul);
            
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaAmericaSul;
}



public Paises getAmericaSulByID(int idPaises) {
    Paises americaSul = new Paises();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT nome_pais,nome_indicador, tipo_medida, medida, data_medida FROM fato INNER JOIN continente ON fato.continente_id_continente = continente.id_continente INNER JOIN paises ON continente.id_continente = paises.continente_id_continente INNER JOIN indicador ON continente.id_continente = indicador.continente_id_continente INNER JOIN tipo_indicador ON indicador.tipo_indicador_id_tipo_indicador = tipo_indicador.id_tipo_indicador WHERE id_continente = 1");
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();  
        if (rs.next()) {
            americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nome_pais"));
            americaSul.setTipoMedida(rs.getString("tipo_medida"));
            americaSul.setTotalFocos(rs.getInt("total_focos"));
            americaSul.setDataMedida(rs.getInt("ano_medida"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return americaSul;
}
```

Controller

```
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        int IdAmericaSul = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul"));
        dao.deleteAmericaSul(IdAmericaSul);
        forward = LIST_CONT;
        request.setAttribute("americaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul()); 
    } 
    
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        int IdAmericaSul = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul"));
        Paises americaSul = dao.getAmericaSulByID(IdAmericaSul);
        request.setAttribute("americaSul", americaSul);     
    } 
    
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listaAmericaSul")){
        forward = LIST_CONT;
        request.setAttribute("americaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul());
    }
    
    else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Paises americaSul = new Paises();
    americaSul.setIdPaises(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_pais")));
    americaSul.setNomePais(request.getParameter("nome_pais"));
    americaSul.setTotalFocos(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("total_focos")));
    americaSul.setTipoMedida(request.getParameter("tipo_medida"));
    americaSul.setDataMedida(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ano_medida")));
    

    String IdAmericaSul = request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul");
    if(IdAmericaSul == null || IdAmericaSul.isEmpty())
    {
        dao.addPaises(americaSul);
    }
    else
    {
        americaSul.setIdPaises(Integer.parseInt(IdAmericaSul));
        dao.updateAmericaSul(americaSul);
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_CONT);
    request.setAttribute("IdAmericaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul());
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

e meu banco https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GsUK.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe o trecho do método `getAllAmericaSul`:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select nome_pais, tipo_medida, total_focos, ano_medida FROM fato f INNER JOIN apaises p ON p.id_paises = f.paises_id_paises INNER JOIN aps.indicador i ON i.id_indicador = f.indicador_id_indicador WHERE nome_continente = 'America do Sul'");
```

Veja a consulta do trecho:

`select nome_pais, tipo_medida, total_focos, ano_medida FROM fato f INNER JOIN apaises p ON p.id_paises = f.paises_id_paises INNER JOIN aps.indicador i ON i.id_indicador = f.indicador_id_indicador WHERE nome_continente = 'America do Sul'`

O problema é que a tabela **`apaises`** não existe na sua estrutura de banco de dados, corrija para `paises`.